# How to set docker down but keep containers alive before new one are will be ready

Tags: python, docker, devops

My problem is when i add changes to my dockerfile or docker-compose, after that i do `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up --build -d` and it take a lot of time(approximately 15 minutes).
I want to keep old containers alive before new one are will be ready ...
I tried to use "live-restore" from docker docs, but it not seems to work for me.
My docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
    
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test123
    volumes:
      - "./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=test
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=test
    ports:
      - "5673:5672"

  web:
    build: ./test_phyton
    restart: always

    command: bash -c "/etc/init.d/cron start && export test=dev && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./test_phyton:/app
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - rabbit
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbit
```

Answer (score 1):

After updating your docker-compose file, you only need to run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

for the changes to take effect.

When making changes to your Dockerfile, you only need to run

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

for the changes to take effect.

You do not need to run 'docker-compose down' every time you make a change.

Note that I only tested this with docker version 18.09.6 and docker-compose version 1.27.0

Comment: `docker-compose up -d --build` after this command, old containers stay working?

Comment: The old container stays working while the new one is building. The moment the new container is done building and is brought up is when the old one is torn down.